# Sending multiple SMS using mCore Active x in vb6 and access database

Tags: vba, vb6

I'm using this to send an SMS using mCore ActiveX Component in VB6.  This code is working fine but sometimes it sends a single SMS multiple times (in fact, hundreds of times until I close my application).  Please guide me as I'm very familiar with VB6

```
Public Function SendSMS()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim strSendResult As String
    Dim ij  As Integer
    Dim message As String
    Dim blnAllMsgsSent As Boolean
    Dim message1
    Dim id As Integer
    blnAllMsgsSent = True

    If objSMS.Connect Then

        Timer2.Enabled = False
        ij = 0
        Sql = "SELECT id,message,MobileNo FROM tblSendSMS where status='Pending'  order by id asc;"
        RS.Open Sql, Conn, adOpenDynamic
        If Not RS.EOF Then

            RS.MoveFirst
            Do While Not RS.EOF

                message = RS!message

                If RS!message <> "" Then

                    id = RS!id

                    '' send message now

                    strSendResult = objSMS.SendSMS(MobileNo, message)
                    strSendResult = ""

                    If objSMS.IsError(True, "Application.exe") Then
                        blnAllMsgsSent = False
                    End If

                End If

                If blnAllMsgsSent Then
                    Sql = "update tblSendSMS set status='Sent' where  id=" & id
                    Conn.Execute Sql
                End If


                ij = ij + 1
                RS.MoveNext

            Loop

        End If
        RS.Close
    Else
        SetCommParameters
    End If
    Timer2.Enabled = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a single error then `blnAllMsgsSent` becomes false & the table is never updated with `sent` for that message but also for **all** subsequent messages, causing them to be resent in the next timer event as their status is still `pending`.

You also only set `id` if `RS!message <> ""` but then use it outside of that check in the update SQL so it could contain the id from a previous message.

Comment: no this is code is working good but sometime one sms sent with multiple times when i see in database it show a single sms but when i see on my mobile it show 10 sms receive or many.i think problem in do while statment

Comment: I think you misread Alex K's answer: you have a line which says `blnAllMsgsSent = False` but there is not any line within the `Do While` loop which says `blnAllMsgsSent = True` for that message or any later messages. You probably need to add an `Else` part to the `If objSMS.IsError...` statement